# Logging In With JSP Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, authentication

I have a problem with Hibernate to make login process. All codes are perfectly correct in terms of syntax. NetBeans tell me that my code have no problem. However, when I run the web, and I test the login process, it doesn't reacting and the address is stucked on the doLogin.

All classes have been mapped correctly.
This is my problem: when I try to retrieve data, my code is stucked on a line.

on doLogin servlet (I use the template provided by NetBeans and just filling in my code on the try. Here's in brief:

```
Connect con = new Connect(); //my code is stucked on this line.
//I've done testing where's the cause of the stuck, and this line is the cause.
List logger = con.getLogin(username, password);
```

and to make it clear:

Connect.java

```
public class Connect {
    Session sesi;

        public Connect() {
            sesi = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }



        public List getLogin(String username, String password){
            return sesi.createQuery("from MsUser WHERE username = '"+username+"' and password = '"+password+"'").list();
        }

    }
```

and since that query is HQL, here is the MsUser class:

```
public class MsUser {

    public MsUser() {
    }

    private int userID;
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String gender;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String photo;

    public MsUser(int userID, String username, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password, String gender, String address, String phone, String photo) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.username = username;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


}
```

please help. But I suspect on Connect's constructor as the main cause. Anybody can suggest or fix or tell me what causing me this.

appendix:

```
HibernateUtil.java
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Controller;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author Ginanjar
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: ther is no reason for the code to get stuck in the place you said, check for any breakpoints in the line `new Connect()`

Comment: do you have the DB configured correctly?

Comment: No stacktrace error? Should not block there...

Comment: yes, I've checked all. Maybe anyone else can help? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code in your hibernateUtil.java file:

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = factory.openSession();
        String query = "select reg.username,reg.password from MsUser as reg where reg.username='" + username + "' and reg.password='" + password + "'";
        Query DBquery = session.createQuery(query);
        for (Iterator it = DBquery.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {            it.next();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total rows: " + count);
        if (count == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```